# Codingbat strDist recursion exercise

Tags: java

**Background**

I am currently working on an exercise on codingbat website related to recursion however, my program seems to display wrong results for certain inputs.

**Problem Scenario from codingbat**

> Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively the
>   largest substring which starts and ends with sub and return its
>   length.

e.g

```
strDist("catcowcat", "cat") → 9

strDist("catcowcat", "cow") → 3

strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat") → 9
```

**My Question**

can you help me find the inputs that will make my program display the wrong result ?.

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {

if(str.length() == 0 || sub.length() == 0){
       return 0;
   }

   if( str.length() >= sub.length() ) {

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
       String getSubFront = builder.substring(0, sub.length());
       String getSubEnd = builder.substring(str.length() - sub.length());

       if (!getSubFront.equals(sub)) {
           builder.deleteCharAt(0);
           return strDist(builder.toString(), sub);
       }

       if (!getSubEnd.equals(sub)) {
           builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
           return strDist(builder.toString(), sub);
       }

   }

   return str.length();
}
```

Comment: OK: your solution is overly complicated. Use [`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) and [`String.lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if `str.length()` is less than `sub.length()`?

`strDist("a", "aa")` should return 0, but your program returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way...

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub){
    if(str.length() < sub.length()){
       return 0;
    }
    if(str.startsWith(sub)){
       return str.lastIndexOf(sub) + sub.length();
    }else{
       strDist(str.substring(1),sub);
    }
      if(str.length()==0){
          return 0;
    }
      return strDist(str.substring(1),sub);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution...

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
  if(str.length() < sub.length() ) return 0;
  if(str.substring(0,sub.length()).equals(sub)){
    if(str.substring(str.length()-sub.length(), str.length()).equals(sub)) {
              return str.length();
    }else{
      return strDist(str.substring(0,str.length()-1), sub);
    }
  }
  
  return strDist(str.substring(1,str.length()), sub);
}
```